# Номера блоков рядом с заголовками

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, html5

Задача: провести линию от первого заголовка ко второму, от второго к третьему и т.д. с номером блока

Чтобы было понятно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу придумать как это сделать 
Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: Контейнеру ставите `border-left`, номера списка выносите псевдоэлементом

Comment: Вот вариант решения похожей задачи: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421672/6263942

Comment: Я не могу понять как это вообще можно сделать для такой разметки?
https://jsfiddle.net/644qoLsj/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если воспользоваться автоматической нумерацией которая уже предусмотрена в css и вот описание этого : http://htmlbook.ru/css/counter-reset

вот частичная реализация :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  counter-reset: list;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

span:before {
  counter-increment: list;
  content: " " counter(list);
}

.items {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.parent {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.parent span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(-20px, 0);
  border-right: 4px solid #222;
  padding-right: 9px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
}

.item h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.item p {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="counter"></span>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis, commodi. Voluptate facilis nihil ea aliquam?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="counter"></span>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis, commodi. Voluptate facilis nihil ea aliquam?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="counter"></span>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis, commodi. Voluptate facilis nihil ea aliquam?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="counter"></span>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis, commodi. Voluptate facilis nihil ea aliquam?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

здесь можно посмотреть и добавить или убавить элементы : [codepen.io/pen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OvoZPr?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <h2 class="box__head">Заголовок 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2 class="box__head">Заголовок 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2 class="box__head">Заголовок 3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrap {
  padding: 20px 50px;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 50px 150px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #f00;
  }
  &:nth-child(1):after {
    content: '1';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -20px;
  }
  &:nth-child(2):after {
    content: '2';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -20px;
  }
  &:nth-child(3):after {
    content: '3';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -20px;
  }
  &__head {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```